# Is this list-initialization of an array of unknown size valid in C++0x?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, c++11

Is this list-initialization of an array of unknown size valid in C++0x?

```
int main() { int x[]{0, 1,2,3,4}; return x[0]; }
```

I believe it is valid, but would appreciate some confirmation.

If anyone could quote from the [C++0x-FCD](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf) to support their case, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This goes from `8.5/16` first bullet to `8.5.4` list-initialization and from `8.5.4/3` third bullet to `8.5.1` aggregate initialization and then `8.5.1/4` says

> An array of unknown size initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer-list containing n initializer-clauses, where shall be greater than zero, is deﬁned as having elements

The only difference if the object is an array between `= { ... }` and `{ ... }` is that the first is called *copy-list-initialization* and the second is called *direct-list-initialization*, so both are kinds of list-initialization. The elements of the array are copy-initialized from the elements of the initializer list in both cases.

<strike>Notice that there is a subtle difference between those forms if the array has a size and the list is empty, in which case `8.5.4` second bullet applies:</strike>

```
struct A {
  explicit A();
};

A a[1]{};    // OK: explicit constructor can be used by direct initialization
A a[1] = {}; // ill-formed: copy initialization cannot use explicit constructor
```

This difference does not apply to lists that have content in which case third bullet applies again, though

```
struct A {
  explicit A(int);
};

A a[1]{0};    // ill-formed: elements are copy initialized by 8.5.1
A a[1] = {0}; // ill-formed: same.
```

The FCD changed this compared to the previous draft, and initialization with an empty initializer list now always works even with explicit default constructors. This is because the FCD states that the elements are value-initialized, and value initialization doesn't care about explicitness since it doesn't do overload resolution on default constructors (it couldn't figure out better or worse matches anyway). The previous draft used normal overload resolution on the constructors and thus rejected explicit default constructors during copy initialization. [This defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#990) did that change.

Comment: Thanks :) 
Interesting (but very subtle) point about difference btw initializing with an empty list vs a non-empty list.  I wonder if symmetry there would be a better thing?

Comment: Also do you know if:
int (&&arr)[] = { 1, 2, 3 }; or int (&&arr)[3] = {1,2,3} is allowed?

Comment: @Faisal, notice that also `explicit A(int = 0);` is an explicit default constructor. So this change could affect more programs than one might think first. But i think that the behavior of the FCD is more beneficial, since "explicit" doesn't really say something about default construction, but more about the argument conversions :)

Comment: @Faisal, the situation with array references currently in the Standard is a bit weird. See for instance http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1058 . For your example, we hit "Otherwise the program is ill-formed.". There is some other case for `int(&&arr)[] = {};` which hits "... or if T is any reference type and the initializer list has no elements", but it's illformed because it tries to construct a zero-element array.

Comment: @Faisal, and for `int(&&arr)[] = { 0 }` we have "Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element, the object is initialized from that element;" which however sounds weird because it seems to imply the case can only occur for objects, but in fact in this case it occurs for references. In any case if we replace "object" by "object or reference", then it tries to do `int(&&arr)[] = 0;` which is ill-formed likewise. So in any case, you cannot do that, but it seems the Standard isn't well thought out about array references.

Comment: I feel that `int (&&arr)[2] = {1,2}` and `const int (&arr)[2] = {1,2}` should be clearly allowed by the standard, would you agree?

Comment: I think i'm going to try and post a comment [here](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/c++0x-now-at-fcd.html#makecomment) so that the committee might try and clean this up.  Although you might be more qualified to make the comment.

Comment: However, the misuse of "object" while it applies also to reference not only applies to arrays, it seems. `int const& a = { 0 }` is affected aswell, and ends up at "Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element, the object is initialized from that element".

Comment: @Johannes - Thanks again for your rigorous insight.  
To all others who read this comment, please up vote the answer - the issues addressed by the answer and the author's ensuing comments show deep insight of a difficult topic.  I wish i could upvote it a few more times ;)

Comment: @Faisal, thanks for the praise :) I think i'm not a good commenter on this array-reference issue because i have doubts the committee would be willing to support it (they commented on my issue report saying that they generally want to avoid array temporaries).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is valid, and has been for decades, even in C. The size is simply set to the number of elements supplied. I don't know the reference, unfortunately.

(Added bonus...) If you need the number of elements use `sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x)`. It's safer than hard-coding a constant that may become invalid if you add or remove entries.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, the code in question is missing an `=` (a fact that I missed), without which it isn't valid in any current standard of C or C++.

Comment: Wrong.  Without the = sign, it is only valid in C++0x (not in C++03).